# Why is my SQLite database keep adding those data that have been added?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I just want my SQLite databse add the data one time, but My SQLite database keeps adding those data that have been added when I launch my app? How could I solve this problem? Can someone help me? I appreciate it.

Here is my java main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
public WebView web;
public DBHelper AsongHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initial();
    Insertdata();

}
public void initial() {
    AsongHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    AsongHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    AsongHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    ListView ml = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    List<listview_item>Songlist = AsongHelper.getSongsName();
    listview_adapter ada = new listview_adapter(this, Songlist);
    ml.setAdapter(ada);
    ml.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    web.setWebViewClient(
            new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    );
    web.loadUrl("http://youtu.be/bMqKM9lqX7M");
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    List<String> UrlList =AsongHelper.geturl();
    web.loadUrl(UrlList.get(position));}
public void Insertdata(){
    AsongHelper.insertdata("小幸运", "https://youtu.be/bMqKM9lqX7M", "Jason Chen");
    AsongHelper.insertdata("Love Yourself","https://youtu.be/oyEuk8j8imI","Justin Bieber");
    AsongHelper.insertdata("Gentleman","https://youtu.be/lGVKrj6gpnI","Will Jay");
}
}
```

Here is my database class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ASong.op";
public static final String ASONG_TABLE_NAME = "Asongs";
public static final String ASONG_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String ASONG_COLUMN_SONGSNAME = "SongsName";
public static final String ASONG_COLUMN_URL = "url";
public static final String ASONG_COLUMN_ARTIST = "artist";

public DBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL( "create table Asongs " + "(id integer primary key, SongsName text,url text,artist text)"
    );
}
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Asongs");
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean insertdata  (String songsname, String url, String artist)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ASONG_COLUMN_SONGSNAME,songsname);
    contentValues.put(ASONG_COLUMN_URL,url);
    contentValues.put(ASONG_COLUMN_ARTIST, artist);
    db.insert(ASONG_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}
public List<listview_item> getSongsName(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<listview_item> SongsNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] SongsName={ASONG_COLUMN_SONGSNAME};

    Cursor cusor =  db.query(ASONG_TABLE_NAME,SongsName,null,null,null,null,null);
    //StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(cusor.moveToNext()){
        int index1 = cusor.getColumnIndex(ASONG_COLUMN_SONGSNAME);
        String cid = cusor.getString(index1);
        //buffer.append(cid);
        SongsNameList.add(new listview_item(cid));
        cusor.close();
      ;}
    return SongsNameList;
}
public List<String> geturl(){
    List<String> SongsUrlList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] ColumnUrl={ASONG_COLUMN_URL};
    Cursor cusor =  db.query(ASONG_TABLE_NAME,ColumnUrl,null,null,null,null,null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(cusor.moveToNext()){
        int index2 = cusor.getColumnIndex(ASONG_COLUMN_URL);
        String cid2 = cusor.getString(index2);
        buffer.append(cid2);
        SongsUrlList.add(buffer.toString());
    }
    cusor.close();
    return SongsUrlList;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnCreate runs every time you start up an activity, So, if you run InsertData() in the OnCreate() method of your activity, it's going to insert those records any time you launch your app.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#lifecycle-states

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initial();
    Insertdata();
```

Check [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), it's one way to distribute your app with a pre-populated database.

Comment: But could you please tell me where should I put InserData? What if I want to add more data next time?

Answer (score 0):

Check that data exists in your database in a conditional before calling `InsertData();`

For example,

```
Cursor resultCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable");
if (resultCursor.getCount < 1) { //if there's nothing in the result
    Insertdata();
}
resultCursor.close();
```

Comment: You can keep your code in onCreate by the way. You just need to perform a database check beforehand.
@JimENewtron thanks for your help editing.

Comment: Thanks but what if there are some data have existed and i wanna insert more. Can i still use this method?

Comment: Well that depends on what you're trying to build. Yes, you can always call `InsertData();` again but you need to determine what's best for your app. Where's your data coming from? Is it user-generated (maybe from an EditText)? Is it something you can have inserted after a button click?

Comment: How about update my app? And i don't need the button.

Comment: Can you tell me, how will _You_ know when there's more data to add?

Comment: I mean i want to insert more data in my database and update my app  periodically.